# Me tira 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo una tienda online subida a *Hostinger*.

Aparentemente funciona correctamente la página principal, pero en el momento de pinchar en el menú, carrito de la compra u otra cosa, me tira el siguiente error:

> Falló al cargar los siguientes recursos: El servidor ha respondido con un estado de 500 (Error interno del servidor).
>
> - http://www.pcpaulo.com.esy.es/favicon.ico
> - catalogo

> **Error interno del servidor:**
>
> El servidor encontró un error interno o una configuración incorrecta y no pudo completar su solicitud. Póngase en contacto con el administrador del servidor, **admin@main-hosting.eu** e infórmeles de la hora en que ocurrió el error, y las acciones que realizó justo antes de este error.

He probado a renombrar el archivo **htaccess** y el error interno deja de salir, en este caso sale un error de *Hostinger*. ¿Es posible que el error venga de ese archivo?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /tienda/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /tienda/index.php
</IfModule>
```

También he probado a darle permisos 755 a todas las carpetas subidas a *Hostinger*.

Se está utilizando el framework *CodeIgniter*, no sé si eso puede tener alguna repercusión en el error.

Comment: ¿en tu archivo log hay algún error?

Comment: No no encuentro ningún error

Comment: El error es el signo de admiración `!` que tienes aquí: `<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>` El archivo .htaccess es sumamente delicado, ya que un sólo símbolo de más o de menos en él te puede dejar inactivo todo el sitio web o parte de él.

Comment: He probado a quitarle el signo de admiración y ocurre lo mismo

Comment: el error es de algun script de php, no del htaccess.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @Alex Angelico . Pon un "error_reporting(E_ALL)" al script y revisa la consola del navegador en Network -> XHR y mira a ver que te sale

Answer (score 1):

revisa la ruta base de tu aplicacion, la de tu pc no es la misma a la de hostinger, esto en el archivo `application/config/config.php` variable `$config['base_url']`, ojala se arregla, saludos.